# Using "while loop" for strings

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class example{

    static String next(String base, String n, String m){

        while(m >= n){

            for(int i= n.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
                //i= n.length()-1;
                char digit= n.charAt(i);
                int pos= base.indexOf(digit);

                if(n.charAt((n.length())-1) == 0){
                    n= n.substring(0,i)
                    + base.charAt(pos+1)
                    + n.substring(i+1);

                    break;
                }//if end

                if(pos == base.length()-1){
                    n= n.substring(0,i)
                    + base.charAt(0);

                }//if end

                else{

                    n= n.substring(0,i)
                    + base.charAt(pos+1)
                    +n.substring(i+1);

                    break;
                }//else end

            }//for end

            return n;   
        }//while end

    }//next end

        public static void main(String[] args){

            System.out.print("Enter the Base: ");
            Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
            String base= input.nextLine(); //base number
            System.out.print("Enter Starting Number: ");
            String n= input.nextLine(); // starting number
            System.out.print("Enter the Last Number: ");
            String m= input.nextLine(); //last number

            System.out.println(next(base,n,m));

    }//main end
}//class end
```

Is there a way to make this possible? I need to print results inbetween strings n and m, but the while loop does not work since they are both strings. If I switch the strings to int and back, since i change them to int on the outside of the loop, they don't stay as integers. Any solutions?

Comment: What does 'inbetween strings n and m' mean? Would "Earth" be between "Mars" and "Venus", or what?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that it needs to work with letters as well..

Comment: Please provide an example of input values with the expected output

Comment: so like if i type "ate" and "bee" with the base being "0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" it would print all those letters till it reaches from "ate" to "bee", while listing every combination in between. so i need it to stop at "bee". it needs to work with letters and numbers

Answer (score 0):

As you want to find the string between `n` and `m` , both of which are present in `base`, you can just find the index of both the strings and the find the sub-string of the `base` string using the indexes found earlier.

```
base.substring(base.indexOf(n)+n.length(), base.indexOf(m)-1);
```

[Click](https://ideone.com/dsSHYC) for demo.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: Answer is ok.
Any way should be: 
`base.substring(base.indexOf(n)+n.length(), base.indexOf(m));`
substring(x,y) starts from x (with x index), until y (without y index)